# Is there a list of Unicode encoding range for the Emoji characters?

Tags: iphone, unicode, nsstring, emoji

Is there a list of the Unicode encoding hex of every Emoji character on iPhone? Thanks!

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emoji#Apple_encoding might be helpful.

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/q/41318999/218152

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is [this](http://web.archive.org/web/20091030230412/http://pukupi.com/post/1964/) (at archive.org) what you are looking for

Comment: Link is no longer working, is there a new version somewhere?